# Alert when failure rate stays above 25% for 5 mins

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to create an alert which will fire if the failure rate of requests made stays above 25% for 5 minutes, unless the total number of requests made in the 5 minutes is less than 10.

I have a metric called `result` with the parameter `status="SUCCESS|FAIL"`.

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
avg_over_time(
  (
    (
      sum(rate(result{status="FAIL"}[5m])) /
      sum(rate(result[5m])) unless
      sum(rate(result[5m])) < 10
    ) > BOOL 0.25
  )[5m:] 
)
```

Does this look correct? I am new to Prometheus so I am struggling to wrap my head around the functions and time ranges.

Also, I am using the `sum` function, since the metric has other parameters like `customer_id`, but I want the overall failure rate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in the outer `avg_over_time()` function, since [rate(m[d])](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) already returns **the average** per-second increase rate for the input [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) `m` over the duration `d`.

So the following query returns non-empty result (aka alert) when the average failure rate for the last 5 minutes exceeds 25% unless the number of requests over the last 5 minutes is less than 10:

```
((
  sum(rate(result{status="FAIL"}[5m]))
    /
  sum(rate(result[5m]))
) > 0.25)
and sum(increase(result[5m])) >= 10
```

The query uses [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function for returning the number of requests over the last 5 minutes.

Note that `increase()` function in Prometheus may return unexpected non-integer results when applied to integer counters. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. The workaround is to use VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It returns the expected integer results from `increase()` function -  see [the technical details](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711).